How to do bulk insert using SQLBulkOperations C API
I am trying to do bulk insert of 1000 rows into below table in PostgreSQL using ODBC C APIs. Lets say the data to be inserted is maintained in two arrays int id[1000], char names[1000][50]. I tried to use SQLBuilkOperations/SQL_ADD as in https://github.com/postgresql-interfaces/psqlodbc/blob/main/test/src/bulkoperations-test.c, however in this example I couldn't see SQL query with INSERT. In my usecase I always want to update table, I never want to fetch the data. Could anyone suggest a sample code just to do BULK insert?
Table:
id INTEGER
name VARCHAR(50)
Suggestions or Sample code

I believe this example demonstrates bulk insert:
https://github.com/postgresql-interfaces/psqlodbc/blob/main/test/src/arraybinding-test.c
